# Error when running spring tests on h2 database

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2, spring-test

I am using spring, hibernate, mysql for my app, I am trying to use h2 for testing my repositories and service, however I am getting an error I have not solved for several days.

Here is application properties:

```
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/daskalos
#---enter your username and password------------------
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = admin
#-----------------------------------------------------
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=daskalos
#-----Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)----------------
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server.port=8080`
```

Here is my test properties, that I use for testing:

```
`spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`
```

Here is my test class:

```
`@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection =  EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application-test.properties")
public class TeacherServiceIntegrationTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TeacherServiceIntegrationTestsContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TeacherService teacherService() {
            return new TeacherServiceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public ExperienceService experienceService() {
            return new ExperienceServiceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public RatingService ratingService() {
            return new RatingServiceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public SubjectService subjectService() {
            return new SubjectServiceImpl();
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ExperienceRepository experienceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherToExperienceRepository teacherToExperienceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherRatingRepository teacherRatingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherToRatingRepository teacherToRatingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectRepository subjectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherToSubjectRepository teacherToSubjectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RatingService ratingService;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectService subjectService;

    @Autowired
    private ExperienceService experienceService;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherService teacherService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Teacher teacher1;

    private Student student1;

    private ExperienceDTO experienceDTO1;

    private ExperienceDTO experienceDTO2;

    private TeacherRatingDTO teacherRatingDTO1;

    private TeacherRatingDTO teacherRatingDTO2;

    private SubjectDTO subjectDTO1;

    private SubjectDTO subjectDTO2;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        teacher1 = new Teacher(10L, "Luka", "Kalandadze", "AtLeast^8", "email2",
                UserType.TEACHER, "55555555", "Tbilisi", true, 100, 150);
        student1 = new Student("email1", "AtLeast^8", "Giorgi", "Adikashviili", UserType.STUDENT);
        student1.setID(11L);

        experienceDTO1 = ExperienceDTO.builder().
                ID(1000L).
                employer("Microsoft").
                jobDescription("Code maintenance").
                startDate(new Date(2017, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 19)).
                endDate(null).
                build();

        experienceDTO2 = ExperienceDTO.builder().
                ID(1001L).
                employer("Amazon").
                jobDescription("Code development").
                startDate(new Date(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 8)).
                endDate(new Date(2017, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 19)).
                build();

        teacherRatingDTO1 = TeacherRatingDTO.builder().
                ID(100L).
                studentID(student1.getID()).
                studentComment("very nice teacher").
                rating(5).
                //studentNameSecondName("Malkhaz Verstappen").
                        build();

        teacherRatingDTO2 = TeacherRatingDTO.builder().
                ID(101L).
                studentID(student1.getID()).
                studentComment("not bad teacher").
                rating(3).
                //studentNameSecondName("Karen Horner").
                        build();

        subjectDTO1 = SubjectDTO.builder().
                ID(21L).
                name("Aero Engineering").
                build();
        subjectDTO2 = SubjectDTO.builder().
                ID(21L).
                name("Mechanical Engineering").
                build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddRemoveExperience() {
        Teacher t = userRepository.save(teacher1);
        teacherService.addExperience(t.getID(), experienceDTO1);
        List<ExperienceDTO> teachersExperience = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeachersExperience();
        assertEquals(1, teachersExperience.size());
        assertThat(teachersExperience, contains(experienceDTO1));

        teacherService.addExperience(t.getID(), experienceDTO2);
        teachersExperience = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeachersExperience();
        assertEquals(2, teachersExperience.size());
        assertThat(teachersExperience, containsInAnyOrder(experienceDTO2, experienceDTO1));

        teacherService.removeExperience(experienceDTO1);
        teachersExperience = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeachersExperience();
        assertEquals(1, teachersExperience.size());
        assertThat(teachersExperience, contains(experienceDTO2));

        teacherService.removeExperience(experienceDTO2);
        teachersExperience = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeachersExperience();
        assertEquals(0, teachersExperience.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddRemoveRating() {
        Teacher t = userRepository.save(teacher1);
        Student s = userRepository.save(student1);
        teacherService.addRating(t.getID(), teacherRatingDTO1);
        List<TeacherRatingDTO> teacherRatings = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherRatings();
        assertEquals(1, teacherRatings.size());
        assertThat(teacherRatings, contains(teacherRatingDTO1));

        teacherService.addRating(t.getID(), teacherRatingDTO2);
        teacherRatings = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherRatings();
        assertEquals(2, teacherRatings.size());
        assertThat(teacherRatings, containsInAnyOrder(teacherRatingDTO2, teacherRatingDTO1));

        teacherService.removeRating(teacherRatingDTO1);
        teacherRatings = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherRatings();
        assertEquals(1, teacherRatings.size());
        assertThat(teacherRatings, contains(teacherRatingDTO2));

        teacherService.removeRating(teacherRatingDTO2);
        teacherRatings = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherRatings();
        assertEquals(0, teacherRatings.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddRemoveSubject() {
        Teacher t = userRepository.save(teacher1);
        teacherService.addSubject(t.getID(), subjectDTO1);
        List<SubjectDTO> teacherSubjects = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherSubjects();
        assertEquals(1, teacherSubjects.size());
        assertThat(teacherSubjects, contains(subjectDTO1));

        teacherService.addSubject(t.getID(), subjectDTO2);
        teacherSubjects = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherSubjects();
        assertEquals(2, teacherSubjects.size());
        assertThat(teacherSubjects, containsInAnyOrder(subjectDTO2, subjectDTO1));

        teacherService.removeSubject(t.getID(), subjectDTO1);
        teacherSubjects = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherSubjects();
        assertEquals(1, teacherSubjects.size());
        assertThat(teacherSubjects, contains(subjectDTO2));

        teacherService.removeSubject(t.getID(), subjectDTO2);
        teacherSubjects = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(teacher1.getID()).getTeacherSubjects();
        assertEquals(0, teacherSubjects.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateTeacher() {
        Teacher t = userRepository.save(teacher1);
        teacherService.updateTeacher(TeacherDTO.builder().ID(t.getID()).name("Levani").build());
        String newName = teacherService.getTeacherDTO(t.getID()).getName();
    }
}`
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table experience (
       id bigint not null,
        employer varchar(255),
        end_date datetime(6),
        job_description varchar(255),
        start_date datetime(6),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1388) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "\000d\000a    create table experience (\000d\000a       id bigint not null,\000d\000a        employer varchar(255),\000d\000a        end_date datetime(6),\000d\000a        job_description varchar(255),\000d\000a        start_date datetime(6),\000d\000a        primary key (id)\000d\000a    ) engine[*]=InnoDB"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
`
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase()` needs to have `replace = NONE`, otherwise your custom JDBC URL with special settings (for MySQL compatibility mode) will be ignored.